# Alexandroff One Point Compactification of $[0,1]\times[0,1)$

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I have to find the Alexandroff One Point Compactification of $[0,1]\times[0,1)$, which should be a triangle.

I need a map $\phi:[0,1]\times[0,1)\to \mathrm{T}\setminus\{\mathrm{V}\}$, where $\mathrm{T}=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2:x,y\ge 0\text{ and }x+y\le 1\}\;.$

Could $\phi(x,y)=(x|y|,y)$ work?

Comment: Why not try it and see?  Also, I am confused as to why your proposed map has absolute value signs in it  - the domain is pairs of non-negative numbers.  And a hint:  If $x,y$ are both close to $1$, what can you say about $x|y| + y$?

Comment: Which point of $T$ is $V$?